# Definition of semistable curve in Liu Qing's book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, notation

In Liu Qing's book [Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves], he defines a curve over an algebraically closed field to be semistable if it is at worst nodal.

But in many other places, semistable curves are defined to be at worst nodal, **and a smooth rational component meets other components at at least 2 points**, for some sort of GIT purpose.

Is Liu Qing using improper notations, or is there some history of the very name "semistable" that I don't know.